# How to obtain the nth random "nextInt" value?

Tags: java, random

When using class java.util.Random, how can one get the value obtained from calling the method nextInt() N times, but in a much more efficient way (in O(1) specifically)?

For example, if I construct a Random object with a particular seed value, and I want to get the 100,000th "nextInt() value" (that is, the value obtained after calling the method nextInt() 100,000 times) in a fast way, could I do it?

Assume, for simplicity, version 1.7.06 of the JDK, since it may be required to know the exact values of some private fields in class Random. And speaking of, I found the following fields to be relevant in the calculation of a random value:

```
private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
private static final long addend = 0xBL;
private static final long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
```

After exploring a bit about randomness, I found that random values are obtained using a *Linear congruential generator*. The actual method that executes the algorithm is method next(int):

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

The relevant line for the algorithm is the one that obtains the next seed value:

```
nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
```

So, to be more specific, is there a way that I can generalize this formula to obtain the "nth nextseed" value? I'm assuming here that after having that, I can then simply obtain the nth int value by letting the variable "bits" be 32 (the method nextInt() simply calls next(32) and returns the result).

Thanks in advance

PS: Perhaps this is a question more suitable for [mathexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in `O(log N)` time. Starting with `s(0)`, if we ignore the modulus (2<sup>48</sup>) for the moment, we can see (using `m` and `a` as shorthand for `multiplier` and `addend`) that

```
s(1) = s(0) * m + a
s(2) = s(1) * m + a = s(0) * m² + (m + 1) * a
s(3) = s(2) * m + a = s(0) * m³ + (m² + m + 1) * a
...
s(N) = s(0) * m^N + (m^(N-1) + ... + m + 1) * a
```

Now, `m^N (mod 2^48)` can easily be computed in `O(log N)` steps by modular exponentiation by repeated squaring.

The other part is a bit more complicated. Ignoring the modulus again for the moment, the geometric sum is

```
(m^N - 1) / (m - 1)
```

What makes computing this modulo `2^48` a bit nontrivial is that `m - 1` is not coprime to the modulus. However, since

```
m = 0x5DEECE66DL
```

the greatest common divisor of `m-1` and the modulus is 4, and `(m-1)/4` has a modular inverse `inv` modulo `2^48`. Let

```
c = (m^N - 1) (mod 4*2^48)
```

Then

```
(c / 4) * inv ≡ (m^N - 1) / (m - 1) (mod 2^48)
```

So

- compute `M ≡ m^N (mod 2^50)`
- compute `inv`

to obtain

```
s(N) ≡ s(0)*M + ((M - 1)/4)*inv*a (mod 2^48)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. See my answer for a specific implementation in java.

Comment: Good. It was too late in the night for me to actually implement it ;) Just a note, since the modulus is a power of 2, and Java guarantees wrap-around for `long` arithmetic, i.e. arithmetic modulo 2^64, there's no actual need to use `BigInteger`, if performance is critical, using plain `long` will probably be faster.

Comment: Yes, I thought there may be some shortcuts. Ultimately, though, what lead me to use BigInteger in the first place was the immediate availability of functions such as modPow(power, mod) and modInverse(mod). In retrospect, looking at the code, I can still use BigInteger for the modInverse function since it is only calculated once.

Comment: Yup, `BigInteger` relieves you of the burden to write your own functions. You don't need to call `modInverse` at all, you can compute it once and have it `private static final long inverse = 0x11018AFE8493L;`. You would only need to compute it if you changed the multiplier, and then you also need to adjust the power of 2 dividing `multiplier-1`.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted the answer from Daniel Fischer as it is correct and gives the general solution. Using Daniel's answer, here is a concrete example with java code that shows a basic implementation of the formula (I used class BigInteger extensively so it may not be optimal, but I confirmed a significant speedup over the rudimentary way of actually calling the method nextInt() N times):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;


public class RandomNthNextInt {

    // copied from java.util.Random =========================
    private static final long   multiplier  = 0x5DEECE66DL;
    private static final long   addend      = 0xBL;
    private static final long   mask        = (1L << 48) - 1;


    private static long initialScramble(long seed) {

        return (seed ^ multiplier) & mask;
    }

    private static int getNextInt(long nextSeed) {

        return (int)(nextSeed >>> (48 - 32));
    }
    // ======================================================

    private static final BigInteger mod = BigInteger.valueOf(mask + 1L);
    private static final BigInteger inv = BigInteger.valueOf((multiplier - 1L) / 4L).modInverse(mod);


    /**
     * Returns the value obtained after calling the method {@link Random#nextInt()} {@code n} times from a
     * {@link Random} object initialized with the {@code seed} value.
     * <p>
     * This method does not actually create any {@code Random} instance, instead it applies a direct formula which
     * calculates the expected value in a more efficient way (close to O(log N)).
     * 
     * @param seed
     *            The initial seed value of the supposed {@code Random} object
     * @param n
     *            The index (starting at 1) of the "nextInt() value"
     * @return the nth "nextInt() value" of a {@code Random} object initialized with the given seed value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If {@code n} is not positive
     */
    public static long getNthNextInt(long seed, long n) {

        if (n < 1L) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
        }

        final BigInteger seedZero = BigInteger.valueOf(initialScramble(seed));
        final BigInteger nthSeed = calculateNthSeed(seedZero, n);

        return getNextInt(nthSeed.longValue());
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateNthSeed(BigInteger seed0, long n) {

        final BigInteger largeM = calculateLargeM(n);
        final BigInteger largeMmin1div4 = largeM.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(4L));

        return seed0.multiply(largeM).add(largeMmin1div4.multiply(inv).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(addend))).mod(mod);
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateLargeM(long n) {

        return BigInteger.valueOf(multiplier).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(n), BigInteger.valueOf(1L << 50));
    }

    // =========================== Testing stuff ======================================

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final long n = 100000L; // change this to test other values
        final long seed = 1L; // change this to test other values

        System.out.println(n + "th nextInt (formula) = " + getNthNextInt(seed, n));
        System.out.println(n + "th nextInt (slow)    = " + getNthNextIntSlow(seed, n));
    }

    private static int getNthNextIntSlow(long seed, long n) {

        if (n < 1L) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
        }

        final Random rand = new Random(seed);
        for (long eL = 0; eL < (n - 1); eL++) {
            rand.nextInt();
        }
        return rand.nextInt();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Notice the method initialScramble(long), which is used to get the first seed value. This is the behavior of class Random when initializing an instance with a specific seed.