# what is the fastest way to get the nth nextInt value?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random, int

I have to find the nth nextInt of each array element.
The code below is really slow as the array elements are over 40k, and each array element is over a million.

```
int[] numbers ={1000000,1004300,2204000,1306000...40k+};
for (int i = 0; i <numbers.length; i++) {
Random ran = new Random(1234);
    int nex = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n <numbers[i]; n++) {
        nex = ran.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Next int value: " + nex);
}
```

Is there a faster way to get the 1 millionth nextInt? if yes please how?

Comment: You have a typo in your first loop. It should be `i++` instead of `n++`.

Comment: So, what are you expecting? You are calling `nextInt` at least 40 billion times ... Do you really do the printout every time. Because that will definitely slow down the whole thing enormously

Comment: The printout is not really the problem, as I can use ArrayList to capture the nextInt and later printout the ArrayList with all the numbers. The main problem is looping 40 billion times. I was thinking if a method like get(Index)  exist that I could use, instead of looping millions of time for each element. @derpirscher

Comment: Typically, these built-in random generators have a state, which changes for every random. Simply speaking, the random you got by `nexiInt` might serve as seed for the next random number. So, for calculating the 10th, you would need the 9th, for that you would need the 8th, ... There may be other generators which support your needs. The one built-in in Java doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616408/7285198 - probably, this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the "seed" value of your random number generator. This means that it will produce the same sequence of random numbers every time this code runs, and so the sequence is predictable.

If you were truly generating random numbers, generating the millionth random number would be the same as generating the first random number, because no one could tell the difference between those two unpredictable results.

So, the first potential optimization is: don't use a predictable sequence, and take the first random number. This is would require a small, constant time.

Next, if you require this sort of repeatability, you could pre-compute them, and your code would include that table of results. Then you can look the results in constant time.

If you need a repeatable sequence that looks sort of random, but it doesn't have to be this particular sequence, you could use a different pseudo-random generator. For example, you could encrypt the "index" (1 million in your example) with a block cipher, and use some bytes from the result. This is also a constant time algorithm, regardless of the index.

Here's an implementation of the last idea:

```
public class PredictableSequenceGenerator {

  private final int[] numbers;

  public PredictableSequenceGenerator(int[] numbers) {
    this.numbers = Objects.requireNonNull(numbers);
  }

  public int[] generate(long seed) {
    ByteBuffer src = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    src.putLong(seed).putLong(seed);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(src.array(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher;
    try {
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to initialize generator.", ex);
    }
    int[] results = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < numbers.length; ++idx) {
      src.clear();
      src.putInt(0, idx);
      dst.clear();
      try {
        cipher.doFinal(src, dst);
      } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to transform index.", ex);
      }
      results[idx] = dst.flip().getInt();
    }
    return results;
  }

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    int[] numbers = { 1000000, 1004300, 2204000, 1306000, /* 40k+ */ };
    PredictableSequenceGenerator gen = new PredictableSequenceGenerator(numbers);
    int[] random = gen.generate(1234);
    for (int r : random)
      System.out.println(r);
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't point out that the seed number is subject to change.

Comment: @HitherJoe Then how can anyone tell whether the result were produced with your algorithm or not?

Comment: @HitherJoe And another important question is whether you need to use `java.util.Random` (a linear congruential generator) to produce the results. If you want to change the seed, compute the nth random number, be able to reliably re-produce a sequence for that seed later, then LCG is difficult, but the encryption idea is easy and fast. It just won't agree with `java.util.Random`.

Comment: Are the seed values predefined anyhow? If not, what difference does it make, if you take the first or the 1000000th random?

Comment: @erickson any random generator will do, which other one would you suggest?

Comment: @HitherJoe I updated my answer with code for my last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the seed, so that the random sequence is the same every time? Then you could sort your numbers array ascending. Then  for the second element you don't need to reset the random generator but can just continue where you left. This way you will have to call `nextInt` only as often as the highest number in your array is, instead of 40 billion times

Comment: That means I will have to hold millions of numbers in an array, which I think would be heavy on memory. The seed may not be the same.

Comment: @HitherJoe No, he's suggesting that you sort `numbers`, with its 40k+ elements. You already have that in memory.

Comment: @erickson, thank you. It's making sense now. I will try to do that and get back to you guys. Before then if you come up with a better solution, I would appreciate.

Comment: No, you sort the 40k numbers. Then for the first random you loop for instance 1000000 times. Next is for instance 1000123. But instead of looping 1000123 times, you only need 123 loops, because the first 1000000 will be the same. Of course, you must not reinitialize the random generator between the loops. But as you stated above, your seed changes, which makes this answer obsolete